# terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit) DIFFERENT ERROR

Tags: c

I faced another problem here again with terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
But I found that there's an output here :
Sequential elapsedTime: 97906.976232 ms
It shows that only my parallel function got wrong. Can anyone tell me why?
Here's how function work:
This program compared a parallel and a normal large matrix multiplying. I use a strassen function hope to make it faster than only parallel. But now I faced problem which I can't understand right now. Can some help?

```
/*Author: Sayak Bera*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 2000
void Madd(int* A, int* B, int* C, int n, int x){
    //   printf("AAAAddd\n\n\n");
    int i,j, m=x>0?n/2:n;
//parallel
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) 
    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
            *(C+i*m+j) = *(A+i*n+j) + *(B+i*n+j);
}

void Msub(int* A, int* B, int* C, int n, int x){
     // printf("AAAAsss\n\n\n");
//parallel
    //#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) 
    int i,j, m=x>0?n/2:n;
    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
            *(C+i*m+j) = *(A+i*n+j) - *(B+i*n+j);
}

void strassen(int* A, int* B, int* C, int n){
    int i,j;
//NOT possible for 2000*2000
    if(n==2){

        int P=(*A+*(A+n+1))*(*B+*(B+n+1));  //P=(A[0][0]+A[1][1])*(B[0][0]+B[1][1])
        int Q=(*(A+n)+*(A+n+1))*(*B);   //Q=(A[1][0]+A[1][1])*B[0][0]
        int R=(*A)*(*(B+1)-*(B+n+1));   //R=A[0][0]*(B[0][1]-B[1][1])
        int S=(*(A+n+1))*(*(B+n)-*B);   //S=A[1][1]*(B[1][0]-B[0][0])
        int T=(*A+*(A+1))*(*(B+n+1));   //T=(A[0][0]+A[0][1])*B[1][1]
        int U=(*(A+n)-*A)*(*B+*(B+1));  //U=(A[1][0]-A[0][0])*(B[0][0]+B[0][1])
        int V=(*(A+1)-*(A+n+1))*(*(B+n)+*(B+n+1));  //V=(A[0][1]-A[1][1])*(B[1][0]+B[1][1])
// master parallel??
        *C=P+S-T+V;
        *(C+1)=R+T;
        *(C+n)=Q+S;
        *(C+n+1)=P+R-Q+U;
    }
/////////////////////////////////
    else{
        
        int m=n/2, i, j;
//      printf("else m is %d, n is %d\n\n", m, n);
        int *x=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*)), *y=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*)), *o=calloc( n*n, sizeof(int) );


        int *P=malloc(sizeof(int*)*N*N), *Q=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n), *R=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n), *S=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n), *T=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n),*U=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n), *V=malloc(sizeof(int*)*n*n);


//malloc not yet
        /*P=(A[0][0]+A[1][1])*(B[0][0]+B[1][1])*/
  //      printf("P1");
        Madd(A, A+m*(n+1), x, n, 1);
        Madd(B, B+m*(n+1), y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, P, m);
//      printf("P2\n\n");
        /*Q=(A[1][0]+A[1][1])*B[0][0]*/
//      printf("Q1");
        Madd(A+m*n, A+m*(n+1), x, n, 1);
        Madd(B, o, y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, Q, m);
//      printf("Q2\n\n");
        /*R=A[0][0]*(B[0][1]-B[1][1])*/
//      printf("R1");
        Madd(A, o, x, n, 1);
        Msub(B+m, B+m*(n+1), y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, R, m);
    //  printf("R2\n\n");
        /*S=A[1][1]*(B[1][0]-B[0][0])*/
//      printf("S1");
        Madd(A+m*(n+1), o, x, n, 1);
        Msub(B+m*n, B, y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, S, m);
//      printf("S2\n\n");
        /*T=(A[0][0]+A[0][1])*B[1][1]*/
//      printf("T1");
        Madd(A, A+m, x, n, 1);
        Madd(B+m*(n+1), o, y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, T, m);
//      printf("T2\n\n");
        /*U=(A[1][0]-A[0][0])*(B[0][0]+B[0][1])*/
        
 //       printf("U1");
        Msub(A+m*n, A, x, n, 1);
        Madd(B, B+m, y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, U, m);
 //       printf("U2\n\n");
        /*V=(A[0][1]-A[1][1])*(B[1][0]+B[1][1])*/
//      printf("V1");
        Msub(A+m, A+m*(n+1), x, n, 1);
        Madd(B+m*n, B+m*(n+1), y, n, 1);
        strassen(x, y, V, m);
//      printf("V2\n\n");

        /*Calculating the 4 parts for the result matrix*/
//        int W[m][m], X[m][m], Y[m][m], Z[m][m];
        int *W=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*)), *X=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*)), *Y=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*)), *Z=calloc(m*m, sizeof(int*));
   //     printf("Final RUN\n\n");
        Msub(V,T,x,m,0);
        Madd(S,x,y,m,0);
        Madd(P,y,W,m,0); // W=P+S-T+V
        Madd(R,T,X,m,0); // X==R+T
        Madd(Q,S,Y,m,0); // Y=Q+S
        Msub(U,Q,x,m,0);
        Madd(R,x,y,m,0);
        Madd(P,y,Z,m,0); // Z=P+R-Q+U

        /*Conquering 4 parts in the result matrix*/
        for (i=0;i<m;i++)
            for (j=0;j<m;j++){
                *(C+i*n+j) = *(W+i*m+j); //C[0][0]=W
                *(C+i*n+j+m) = *(X+i*m+j); //C[0][1]=X
                *(C+(i+m)*n+j) = *(Y+i*m+j); //C[1][0]=Y
                *(C+(i+m)*n+j+m) = *(Z+i*m+j); //C[1][1]=Z
            }
    

    }

    /*free(P);
    free(Q);
    free(R);
    free(S);
    free(T);
    free(U);
    free(V);
    free(W);
    free(X);
    free(Y);
    free(Z);*/
}

void main()
{
    struct timespec t_start, t_end;
    double elapsedTime;
    int i,j,k,m=2048,o=0;
    int *A=malloc(sizeof(int*)*N*N), *B=malloc(sizeof(int*)*N*N),*a=calloc(2048*2048,sizeof(int*)), *b=calloc(2048*2048,sizeof(int*)), **CC=NULL, *C=calloc(2048*2048,sizeof(int*));
    
   

    for( i=0; i<N; i++ )
     for( j=0; j<N; j++ ) {
        *(A+N*i+j) = rand();
        *(B+N*i+j) = rand();
      }

    //printf("led m is %d",m );
   // a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
  //  b=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
    CC=calloc(N, sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        //a[i]=(int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        //b[i]=(int *)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        CC[i]=calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    }        
    /*for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            a[i][j]=A[i][j];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            b[i][j]=B[i][j];*/

    clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t_start);  
    for( i=0; i<N; i++ ){
        for( j=0; j<N; j++ ) {
            for( k=0; k<N; k++ ){
                CC[i][j] += *(A+N*i+k)*(*(B+N*k+j));
            }
        }
    }
    // stop time
   clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t_end);   

   // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
   elapsedTime = (t_end.tv_sec - t_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
   elapsedTime += (t_end.tv_nsec - t_start.tv_nsec) / 1000000.0;
   printf("Sequential elapsedTime: %lf ms\n", elapsedTime);  
    // start time
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t_start);
 //  printf("StarA: mm is %d", m);
    strassen(A,B,C,m);
//   printf("StarB");;
   clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &t_end);   

   // compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
   elapsedTime = (t_end.tv_sec - t_start.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
   elapsedTime += (t_end.tv_nsec - t_start.tv_nsec) / 1000000.0;
   printf("Parallel elapsedTime: %lf ms\n", elapsedTime);
 
   for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=0; j<N; j++){
            if(*(C+i*N+j) != CC[i][j])
                break;
        }
    }
   
    if(i==N && j==N)
        printf("Test pass!!!\n"); 
    else
        printf("Test failed!!!\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        free(CC[i]);

    }
//1 - dimension
    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);
    
    
    free(CC);
   //return 0;
}
```

This function got problem when it was running

```
strassen(a,b,C,m);
```

in int main(){} function

Comment: Time to drop this in to a debugger and figure out this mystery. Saying "it crashes" is not something we can help with unless you can at least hint at where it goes off the rails.

Comment: There is an alarmingly high number of `*` operators in this code. If you're getting this *adventurous* with pointers you need to be *extremely* careful. Tip: `**A` is better written as `A[0][0]`, and so on.

Comment: This function got problem when it was running

strassen(a,b,C,m);
in int main(){} function

Comment: You mean that function that's intimidatingly huge? You're going to have to be more specific than that. You're going to need to step through this code carefully in a debugger.

Comment: Tip: If you want this code *actually* faster it's time to explore using SIMD via [intrinsics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function). Parallel only gets you so far. Vector math is vastly faster. Parallel vector math can be even better depending on the problem.

Comment: `A[i]=(int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));`
do you really need `A` to contain 4000^2 ints? i run it and its stuck on this line

Comment: In general, you're expected to do enough work to be able to ask a specific, narrow question. If you don't know which the line of code crashes, and haven't built a [mre] with only the shortest possible code that creates the same crash when run without changes, you're not there yet.

Comment: Where it crashes is almost never where the problem is.  You overflow an array and it writes over something else in memory and then later (sometimes much later) you try to use that other thing and now that it has been written over it points to something invalid and the program crashes.  You need to test your code in very small pieces and check that you aren't overflowing anything and once all the little pieces are tested you can stick them together.  Otherwise, you will never figure out where you are corrupting memory because where it crashes probably has nothing to do with the actual bug.

Comment: Starry, starry night....

Comment: Thanks for converting to single star pointers (i.e. true 2D arrays in C)--you're on the right track. It makes the code run faster and also makes it easier to use [the usually preferred] array syntax (e.g. `C[i]` vs `*(C + i)`). I had been working on something like that for you. It's very late here now but I'll try to respond tomorrow

Comment: terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)
Right now

Answer (score 0):

Your program gets to a `strassen` arg `n` of 4 and seems to oscillate there with `n` of 2.

I've added a bunch of cross checking and array limit checking.

I think that the very first `Madd` call in `strassen` exceeds the array limits.

Also, by not releasing the temp memory, it consumes a *lot*.

Note that in your revised version, when doing `malloc`, you're using `sizeof(int *)` but you want `sizeof(int)`.

I've fixed those.

I've had to *heavily* refactor the code to add debugging.

I've added a debug/control `struct` for each array.

I rewrote `Madd` and `Msub` arguments so that array bounds checking could be done.

I could have made a zillion transcription mistakes, so you may have to do considerable desk checking.

Here's the fault output. I ran this under `gdb` and did a stack traceback and it's the *first* `Madd` call in `strassen`:

```
Sequential elapsedTime: 1.136087689
Sequential elapsedTime: 0.608301088
mtxcmp: PASS Corig Cmtx
strassen: ENTER A=A B=B C=Cstrass n=512 depth=0
P1
_geofault: curmax -- off=262400 geo_wid=500 geo_hgt=500 geomax=250000 geo_sym=A
```

---

Here's all the source. I split things into multiple files. To preserve that, the following is an extractable archive.

Save the following to a temp file (e.g. `/tmp/archive`). Do `cd /tmp`. Then, do `perl /tmp/archive -go` and it will created a `strassen` subdirectory. cd to that directory (`/tmp/strassen`) and type `make`.

You may have to modify the `Makefile` to add things to `CFLAGS`:

```
make COPTS="-DDEBUG -DCHECK"
```

*Caveat:* It may take *more* effort to understand the debug stuff I've added than to debug it yourself -- YMMV

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# FILE: ovcbin/ovcext.pm 755
# ovcbin/ovcext.pm -- ovrcat archive extractor
#
# this is a self extracting archive
# after the __DATA__ line, files are separated by:
#   % filename

ovcext_cmd(@ARGV);
exit(0);

sub ovcext_cmd
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    local($xfdata);
    local($xfdiv,$divcur,%ovcdiv_lookup);

    $pgmtail = "ovcext";
    ovcinit();
    ovcopt(\@argv,qw(opt_go opt_f opt_t));

    $xfdata = "ovrcat::DATA";
    $xfdata = \*$xfdata;

    ovceval($xfdata);

    ovcfifo($zipflg_all);

    ovcline($xfdata);

    $code = ovcwait();

    ovcclose(\$xfdata);

    ovcdiv();

    ovczipd_spl()
        if ($zipflg_spl);
}

sub ovceval
{
    my($xfdata) = @_;
    my($buf,$err);

    {
        $buf = <$xfdata>;
        chomp($buf);

        last unless ($buf =~ s/^%\s+([\@\$;])/$1/);

        eval($buf);

        $err = $@;
        unless ($err) {
            undef($buf);
            last;
        }

        chomp($err);
        $err = " (" . $err . ")"
    }

    sysfault("ovceval: bad options line -- '%s'%s\n",$buf,$err)
        if (defined($buf));
}

sub ovcline
{
    my($xfdata) = @_;
    my($buf);
    my($tail);

    while ($buf = <$xfdata>) {
        chomp($buf);

        if ($buf =~ /^%\s+(.+)$/) {
            $tail = $1;
            ovcdiv($tail);
            next;
        }

        print($xfdiv $buf,"\n")
            if (ref($xfdiv));
    }

}

sub ovcdiv
{
    my($ofile) = @_;
    my($mode);
    my($xfcur);
    my($err,$prt);

    ($ofile,$mode) = split(" ",$ofile);

    $mode = oct($mode);
    $mode &= 0777;

    {
        unless (defined($ofile)) {
            while ((undef,$divcur) = each(%ovcdiv_lookup)) {
                close($divcur->{div_xfdst});
            }
            last;
        }

        $ofile = ovctail($ofile);

        $divcur = $ovcdiv_lookup{$ofile};
        if (ref($divcur)) {
            $xfdiv = $divcur->{div_xfdst};
            last;
        }
        undef($xfdiv);

        if (-e $ofile) {
            msg("ovcdiv: file '%s' already exists -- ",$ofile);

            unless ($opt_f) {
                msg("rerun with -f to force\n");
                last;
            }

            msg("overwriting!\n");
        }

        unless (defined($err)) {
            ovcmkdir($1)
                if ($ofile =~ m,^(.+)/[^/]+$,);
        }

        msg("$pgmtail: %s %s",ovcnogo("extracting"),$ofile);
        msg(" chmod %3.3o",$mode)
            if ($mode);
        msg("\n");

        last unless ($opt_go);
        last if (defined($err));

        $xfcur = ovcopen(">$ofile");

        $divcur = {};
        $ovcdiv_lookup{$ofile} = $divcur;

        if ($mode) {
            chmod($mode,$xfcur);
            $divcur->{div_mode} = $mode;
        }

        $divcur->{div_xfdst} = $xfcur;
        $xfdiv = $xfcur;
    }
}

sub ovcinit
{

    {
        last if (defined($ztmp));
        $ztmp = "/tmp/ovrcat_zip";

        $PWD = $ENV{PWD};

        $quo_2 = '"';

        $ztmp_inp = $ztmp . "_0";
        $ztmp_out = $ztmp . "_1";
        $ztmp_perl = $ztmp . "_perl";

        ovcunlink();

        $ovcdbg = ($ENV{"ZPXHOWOVC"} != 0);
    }
}

sub ovcunlink
{

    _ovcunlink($ztmp_inp,1);
    _ovcunlink($ztmp_out,1);
    _ovcunlink($ztmp_perl,($pgmtail ne "ovcext") || $opt_go);
}

sub _ovcunlink
{
    my($file,$rmflg) = @_;
    my($found,$tag);

    {
        last unless (defined($file));

        $found = (-e $file);

        $tag //= "notfound"
            unless ($found);
        $tag //= $rmflg ? "cleaning" : "keeping";

        msg("ovcunlink: %s %s ...\n",$tag,$file)
            if (($found or $ovcdbg) and (! $ovcunlink_quiet));

        unlink($file)
            if ($rmflg and $found);
    }
}

sub ovcopt
{
    my($argv) = @_;
    my($opt);

    while (1) {
        $opt = $argv->[0];
        last unless ($opt =~ s/^-/opt_/);

        shift(@$argv);
        $$opt = 1;
    }
}

sub ovctail
{
    my($file,$sub) = @_;
    my(@file);

    $file =~ s,^/,,;
    @file = split("/",$file);

    $sub //= 2;

    @file = splice(@file,-$sub)
        if (@file >= $sub);

    $file = join("/",@file);

    $file;
}

sub ovcmkdir
{
    my($odir) = @_;
    my(@lhs,@rhs);

    @rhs = split("/",$odir);

    foreach $rhs (@rhs) {
        push(@lhs,$rhs);

        $odir = join("/",@lhs);

        if ($opt_go) {
            next if (-d $odir);
        }
        else {
            next if ($ovcmkdir{$odir});
            $ovcmkdir{$odir} = 1;
        }

        msg("$pgmtail: %s %s ...\n",ovcnogo("mkdir"),$odir);

        next unless ($opt_go);

        mkdir($odir) or
            sysfault("$pgmtail: unable to mkdir '%s' -- $!\n",$odir);
    }
}

sub ovcopen
{
    my($file,$who) = @_;
    my($xf);

    $who //= $pgmtail;
    $who //= "ovcopen";

    open($xf,$file) or
        sysfault("$who: unable to open '%s' -- $!\n",$file);

    $xf;
}

sub ovcclose
{
    my($xfp) = @_;
    my($ref);
    my($xf);

    {
        $ref = ref($xfp);
        last unless ($ref);

        if ($ref eq "GLOB") {
            close($xfp);
            last;
        }

        if ($ref eq "REF") {
            $xf = $$xfp;
            if (ref($xf) eq "GLOB") {
                close($xf);
                undef($$xfp);
            }
        }
    }

    undef($xf);

    $xf;
}

sub ovcnogo
{
    my($str) = @_;

    unless ($opt_go) {
        $str = "NOGO-$str";
        $nogo_msg = 1;
    }

    $str;
}

sub ovcdbg
{

    if ($ovcdbg) {
        printf(STDERR "[%d] ",$$);
        printf(STDERR @_);
    }
}

sub msg
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
}

sub msgv
{

    $_ = join(" ",@_);
    print(STDERR $_,"\n");
}

sub sysfault
{

    printf(STDERR @_);
    exit(1);
}

sub ovcfifo
{
}

sub ovcwait
{
    my($code);

    if ($pid_fifo) {
        waitpid($pid_fifo,0);
        $code = $? >> 8;
    }

    $code;
}

sub prtstr
{
    my($val,$fmtpos,$fmtneg) = @_;

    {
        unless (defined($val)) {
            $val = "undef";
            last;
        }

        if (ref($val)) {
            $val = sprintf("(%s)",$val);
            last;
        }

        $fmtpos //= "'%s'";

        if (defined($fmtneg) && ($val <= 0)) {
            $val = sprintf($fmtneg,$val);
            last;
        }

        $val = sprintf($fmtpos,$val);
    }

    $val;
}

sub prtnum
{
    my($val) = @_;

    $val = prtstr($val,"%d");

    $val;
}

END {
    msg("$pgmtail: rerun with -go to actually do it\n")
        if ($nogo_msg);
    ovcunlink();
}

1;
package ovrcat;
__DATA__
% ;
% strassen/strassen.h
// Strassen's Algorithm for Matrix Multiplication using Divide & Conquer

#ifndef _strassen_strassen_h_
#define _strassen_strassen_h_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef _STRASSEN_GLO_
#define EXTRN_STRASSEN      /**/
#else
#define EXTRN_STRASSEN      extern
#endif

#ifndef CHECK
#define CHECK       1
#endif
#ifndef SMALL
#define SMALL       1
#endif

#define inline_always       static inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        _sysfault(); \
    } while (0)

#if DEBUG || _USE_ZPRT_
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        fflush(stdout); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
    } while (0)
#endif

typedef int *dat_p;
typedef unsigned int u32;

#if SMALL
#define N       (2000 / 4)
#define BIG     (2048 / 4)
#else
#define N       2000
#define BIG     2048
#endif

typedef struct mtxgeo {
    u32 geo_magic;
    struct mtxgeo *geo_next;
    const char *geo_sym;
    int geo_hgt;
    int geo_wid;
} mtxgeo_t;

#define GEOMAGIC    0xDEADBEEF

EXTRN_STRASSEN mtxgeo_t *geofree;
EXTRN_STRASSEN mtxgeo_t *geobusy;

EXTRN_STRASSEN double t_start;
EXTRN_STRASSEN double t_end;

#include <strassen/strassen.proto>

inline_always mtxgeo_t *
mtxgeo(int *mtx)
{
    void *vp;
    mtxgeo_t *geo;

    vp = mtx;
    vp -= sizeof(mtxgeo_t);

    geo = vp;

#if CHECK
    if (geo->geo_magic != GEOMAGIC)
        sysfault("mtxgeo: bad magic\n");
#endif

    return geo;
}

inline_always int *
mtxloc(int *mtx,int y,int x)
{
    mtxgeo_t *geo = mtxgeo(mtx);

    mtx += (y * geo->geo_wid);
    mtx += x;

    return mtx;
}

inline_always const char *
mtxsym(int *mtx)
{
    mtxgeo_t *geo = mtxgeo(mtx);
    return geo->geo_sym;
}

inline_always int *
mtxoffchk(int *mtx,int off,int m,int n)
{

#if CHECK
    mtx = _mtxoffchk(mtx,off,m,n);
#else
    mtx += off;
#endif

    return mtx;
}

#endif
% strassen/arith.c
// strassen/arith.c -- basic add/sub

#include <strassen/strassen.h>

void
Madd_orig(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int x)
{
    int i,
     j,
     m = x > 0 ? n / 2 : n;

//parallel
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            *(C + i * m + j) = *(A + i * n + j) + *(B + i * n + j);
}

void
MaddX(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;

//parallel
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int iN = i * n;

        int *Ap = &A[iN];
        int *Bp = &B[iN];
        int *Cp = &C[i * m];

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
#if 0
            *(C + i * m + j) = *(A + i * n + j) + *(B + i * n + j);
#else
            Cp[j] = Ap[j] + Bp[j];
#endif
        }
    }
}

void
Msub_orig(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int x)
{
    int i, j;
    int m = x > 0 ? n / 2 : n;

//parallel
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            *(C + i * m + j) = *(A + i * n + j) - *(B + i * n + j);
}

void
MsubX(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;

//parallel
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int iN = i * n;

        int *Ap = &A[iN];
        int *Bp = &B[iN];
        int *Cp = &C[i * m];

        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
#if 0
            *(C + i * m + j) = *(A + i * n + j) + *(B + i * n + j);
#else
            Cp[j] = Ap[j] - Bp[j];
#endif
        }
    }
}

void
Madd0(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n)
{
    int m = n;

    A = mtxoffchk(A,0,n,m);
    B = mtxoffchk(B,0,n,m);
    C = mtxoffchk(C,0,m,m);

    MaddX(A,B,C,n,m);
}

void
Madd1(int *A,int Aoff, int *B,int Boff, int *C, int n)
{
    int m = n / 2;

    A = mtxoffchk(A,Aoff,n,m);
    B = mtxoffchk(B,Boff,n,m);
    C = mtxoffchk(C,0,m,m);

    MaddX(A,B,C,n,m);
}

void
Msub0(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n)
{
    int m = n;

    A = mtxoffchk(A,0,n,m);
    B = mtxoffchk(B,0,n,m);
    C = mtxoffchk(C,0,m,m);

    MsubX(A,B,C,n,m);
}

void
Msub1(int *A,int Aoff, int *B,int Boff, int *C, int n)
{
    int m = n / 2;

    A = mtxoffchk(A,Aoff,n,m);
    B = mtxoffchk(B,Boff,n,m);
    C = mtxoffchk(C,0,m,m);

    MsubX(A,B,C,n,m);
}
% strassen/core.c
// strassen/core.c -- strassen function

#include <strassen/strassen.h>

void
strassen(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n)
{
    static int depth = 0;

    dbgprt("strassen: ENTER A=%s B=%s C=%s n=%d depth=%d\n",
        mtxsym(A),mtxsym(B),mtxsym(C),n,depth);

    ++depth;
    if (depth > 40)
        sysfault("strassen: depth overflow n=%d depth=%d\n",n,depth);

    t_end = tscgetf();
    t_end -= t_start;
    if (t_end > 2.0)
        sysfault("strassen: timeout\n");

//NOT possible for 2000*2000
    if (n == 2) {
        // P=(A[0][0]+A[1][1])*(B[0][0]+B[1][1])
        int P = (*A + *(A + n + 1)) * (*B + *(B + n + 1));

        // Q=(A[1][0]+A[1][1])*B[0][0]
        int Q = (*(A + n) + *(A + n + 1)) * (*B);

        // R=A[0][0]*(B[0][1]-B[1][1])
        int R = (*A) * (*(B + 1) - *(B + n + 1));

        // S=A[1][1]*(B[1][0]-B[0][0])
        int S = (*(A + n + 1)) * (*(B + n) - *B);

        // T=(A[0][0]+A[0][1])*B[1][1]
        int T = (*A + *(A + 1)) * (*(B + n + 1));

        // U=(A[1][0]-A[0][0])*(B[0][0]+B[0][1])
        int U = (*(A + n) - *A) * (*B + *(B + 1));

        // V=(A[0][1]-A[1][1])*(B[1][0]+B[1][1])
        int V = (*(A + 1) - *(A + n + 1)) * (*(B + n) + *(B + n + 1));

        // master parallel??
        *C = P + S - T + V;
        *(C + 1) = R + T;
        *(C + n) = Q + S;
        *(C + n + 1) = P + R - Q + U;
    }

/////////////////////////////////
    else {
        int m = n / 2;
        int i, j;

//      printf("else m is %d, n is %d\n\n", m, n);
#if 0
        int *x = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *)),
            *y = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *)),
            *o = calloc(n * n, sizeof(int));
#else
        int *x = mtxacq(m,m,"x");
        int *y = mtxacq(m,m,"y");
        int *o = mtxacq(n,n,"o");
#endif

#if 0
        int *P = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N * N),
            *Q = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n),
            *R = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n),
            *S = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n),
            *T = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n),
            *U = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n),
            *V = malloc(sizeof(int *) * n * n);
#else
        int *P = mtxacq(N,N,"P");
        int *Q = mtxacq(N,N,"Q");
        int *R = mtxacq(N,N,"R");
        int *S = mtxacq(N,N,"S");
        int *T = mtxacq(N,N,"T");
        int *U = mtxacq(N,N,"U");
        int *V = mtxacq(N,N,"V");
#endif

//malloc not yet
        // P=(A[0][0]+A[1][1])*(B[0][0]+B[1][1])

        dbgprt("P1\n");
        Madd1(A, 0, A,m * (n + 1), x, n);
        Madd1(B, 0, B,m * (n + 1), y, n);
        strassen(x, y, P, m);
        dbgprt("P2\n");
        // Q=(A[1][0]+A[1][1])*B[0][0]

        dbgprt("Q1\n");
        Madd1(A,m * n, A,m * (n + 1), x, n);
        Madd1(B,0, o,0, y, n);
        strassen(x, y, Q, m);
        dbgprt("Q2\n");
        // R=A[0][0]*(B[0][1]-B[1][1])

        dbgprt("R1\n");
        Madd1(A,0, o,0, x, n);
        Msub1(B,m, B,m * (n + 1), y, n);
        strassen(x, y, R, m);
        dbgprt("R2\n");

        // S=A[1][1]*(B[1][0]-B[0][0])

        dbgprt("S1\n");
        Madd1(A,m * (n + 1), o, 0, x, n);
        Msub1(B,m * n, B,0, y, n);
        strassen(x, y, S, m);
        dbgprt("S2\n");
        // T=(A[0][0]+A[0][1])*B[1][1]

        dbgprt("T1\n");
        Madd1(A,0, A,m, x, n);
        Madd1(B,m * (n + 1), o,0, y, n);
        strassen(x, y, T, m);
        dbgprt("T2\n");

        // U=(A[1][0]-A[0][0])*(B[0][0]+B[0][1])
        dbgprt("U1\n");

        Msub1(A,m * n, A,0, x, n);
        Madd1(B,0, B,m, y, n);
        strassen(x, y, U, m);
        dbgprt("U2\n");

        // V=(A[0][1]-A[1][1])*(B[1][0]+B[1][1])

        dbgprt("V1\n");
        Msub1(A,m, A,m * (n + 1), x, n);
        Madd1(B,m * n, B,m * (n + 1), y, n);
        strassen(x, y, V, m);
        dbgprt("V2\n");

        // Calculating the 4 parts for the result matrix

//        int W[m][m], X[m][m], Y[m][m], Z[m][m];
#if 0
        int *W = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *)),
            *X = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *)),
            *Y = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *)),
            *Z = calloc(m * m, sizeof(int *));
#else
        int *W = mtxacq(m,m,"W");
        int *X = mtxacq(m,m,"X");
        int *Y = mtxacq(m,m,"Y");
        int *Z = mtxacq(m,m,"Z");
#endif

        dbgprt("Final RUN\n");

        Msub0(V, T, x, m);
        Madd0(S, x, y, m);

        // W=P+S-T+V
        Madd0(P, y, W, m);

        // X==R+T
        Madd0(R, T, X, m);

        // Y=Q+S
        Madd0(Q, S, Y, m);
        Msub0(U, Q, x, m);
        Madd0(R, x, y, m);

        // Z=P+R-Q+U
        Madd0(P, y, Z, m);

        // Conquering 4 parts in the result matrix

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                // C[0][0]=W
                *(C + i * n + j) = *(W + i * m + j);

                // C[0][1]=X
                *(C + i * n + j + m) = *(X + i * m + j);

                // C[1][0]=Y
                *(C + (i + m) * n + j) = *(Y + i * m + j);

                // C[1][1]=Z
                *(C + (i + m) * n + j + m) = *(Z + i * m + j);
            }
        }

        mtxrls(x);
        mtxrls(y);
        mtxrls(o);

        mtxrls(P);
        mtxrls(Q);
        mtxrls(R);
        mtxrls(S);
        mtxrls(T);
        mtxrls(U);
        mtxrls(V);

        mtxrls(W);
        mtxrls(X);
        mtxrls(Y);
        mtxrls(Z);
    }

    --depth;

    dbgprt("strassen: EXIT n=%d depth=%d\n",n,depth);
}
% strassen/mtx.c
// strassen/mtx.c -- matrix allocation

#define _STRASSEN_GLO_
#include <strassen/strassen.h>

int *
mtxacq(int hgt,int wid,const char *sym)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    mtxgeo_t *geo;
    int *mtx = NULL;

    len += sizeof(mtxgeo_t);
    len += sizeof(int) * hgt * wid;

    while (1) {
        void *vp;

        // find existing matrix
        mtxgeo_t *prev = NULL;
        for (geo = geofree;  geo != NULL;  geo = geo->geo_next) {
            if ((geo->geo_hgt == hgt) && (geo->geo_wid == wid))
                break;
            prev = geo;
        }

        // use existing matrix
        if (geo != NULL) {
            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->geo_next = geo->geo_next;
            else
                geofree = geo->geo_next;

            vp = geo;
            vp += sizeof(mtxgeo_t);
            mtx = vp;
            break;
        }

        vp = malloc(len);
        geo = vp;

        geo->geo_hgt = hgt;
        geo->geo_wid = wid;

        // point to matrix data
        vp += sizeof(mtxgeo_t);
        mtx = vp;

        // link it -- we'll find it immediately above
        geo->geo_next = geofree;
        geofree = geo;
    }

    geo->geo_sym = sym;
    geo->geo_magic = GEOMAGIC;

    geo->geo_next = geobusy;
    geobusy = geo;

    return mtx;
}

void
mtxrls(int *mtx)
{
    mtxgeo_t *geo = mtxgeo(mtx);
    mtxgeo_t *prev = NULL;
    mtxgeo_t *next = NULL;
    mtxgeo_t *cur;

    for (cur = geobusy;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->geo_next;
        if (cur == geo)
            break;
        prev = cur;
    }
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->geo_next = next;
    else
        geobusy = next;

    geo->geo_next = geofree;
    geofree = geo;
}

mtxgeo_t *
mtxfree(mtxgeo_t *list)
{
    mtxgeo_t *next;
    mtxgeo_t *cur;

    for (cur = list;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->geo_next;
        free(cur);
    }

    list = NULL;

    return list;
}

void
mtxzero(int *mtx)
{
    mtxgeo_t *geo = mtxgeo(mtx);

    memset(mtx,0,sizeof(int) * geo->geo_hgt * geo->geo_wid);
}

void
mtxcmp(int *lhsbase,int *rhsbase)
{
    int pass = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int *lhs = mtxloc(lhsbase,i,0);
        int *rhs = mtxloc(rhsbase,i,0);

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (lhs[j] != rhs[j]) {
                printf("mtxcmp: MISMATCH [%d,%d] lhs=%d rhs=%d\n",
                    i,j,lhs[j],rhs[j]);
                pass = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (! pass)
            break;
    }

    printf("mtxcmp: %s %s %s\n",
        pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL",
        mtxgeo(lhsbase)->geo_sym,mtxgeo(rhsbase)->geo_sym);

    if (! pass)
        sysfault("mtxcmp: aborting ...\n");
}

int *
_mtxoffchk(int *mtx,int off,int m,int n)
{
    mtxgeo_t *geo = mtxgeo(mtx);
    int geomax = geo->geo_wid * geo->geo_hgt;

    // check starting index
    if (off >= geomax)
        _geofault(geo,off,"off");

    // check ending index
    int curmax = off + (m * n);
    if (curmax > geomax)
        _geofault(geo,curmax,"curmax");

    // point to start
    mtx += off;

    return mtx;
}

void
_geofault(mtxgeo_t *geo,int off,const char *why)
{
    int geomax = geo->geo_wid * geo->geo_hgt;

    sysfault("_geofault: %s -- off=%d geo_wid=%d geo_hgt=%d geomax=%d geo_sym=%s\n",
        why,off,geo->geo_wid,geo->geo_hgt,geomax,geo->geo_sym);
}
% strassen/strassen.c
// strassen/strassen.c -- strassen test

#include <strassen/strassen.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int m = BIG;

#if 0
    int *A = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N * N),
        *B = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N * N),
        *a = calloc(2048 * 2048, sizeof(int *)),
        *b = calloc(2048 * 2048, sizeof(int *)),
        **CC = NULL,
        *C = calloc(2048 * 2048, sizeof(int *));
#else
    dat_p A = mtxacq(N,N,"A");
    dat_p B = mtxacq(N,N,"B");
    //dat_p a = mtxacq(BIG,BIG,"a");
    //dat_p b = mtxacq(BIG,BIG,"b");
    dat_p C = mtxacq(BIG,BIG,"Cstrass");
    dat_p Corig = mtxacq(BIG,BIG,"Corig");
    dat_p Cmtx = mtxacq(BIG,BIG,"Cmtx");
#endif
    int *Cij;

#if 0
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            *(A + N * i + j) = rand();
            *(B + N * i + j) = rand();
        }
    }
#else
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int *pA = mtxloc(A,i,0);
        int *pB = mtxloc(B,i,0);
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            pA[j] = rand();
            pB[j] = rand();
        }
    }
#endif

    // printf("led m is %d",m );
    // a=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);
    // b=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*m);

    // for(i=0;i<N;i++) for(j=0;j<N;j++) a[i][j]=A[i][j]; for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    // for(j=0;j<N;j++) b[i][j]=B[i][j];

    mtxzero(Corig);
    t_start = tscgetf();
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                Corig[(i * N) + j] += *(A + N * i + k) * (*(B + N * k + j));
        }
    }
    t_end = tscgetf();
    printf("Sequential elapsedTime: %.9f\n", t_end - t_start);

    t_start = tscgetf();
    Cij = mtxloc(Cmtx,0,0);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++, ++Cij) {
            int *Ap = mtxloc(A,i,0);
            int *Bp = mtxloc(B,0,j);

            int sum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++, Ap++, Bp += N)
                sum += Ap[0] * Bp[0];

            *Cij = sum;
        }
    }
    t_end = tscgetf();
    printf("Sequential elapsedTime: %.9f\n", t_end - t_start);
    mtxcmp(Corig,Cmtx);

    t_start = tscgetf();
    strassen(A, B, C, m);
    t_end = tscgetf();
    printf("Parallel elapsedTime: %.9f\n", t_end - t_start);
    mtxcmp(Cmtx,C);

    mtxfree(geobusy);
    mtxfree(geofree);

    return 0;
}
% strassen/tsc.c
// strassen/mtx.c -- matrix allocation

#include <strassen/strassen.h>

double
tscgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

void
_sysfault(void)
{

    __asm__ __volatile__("" ::: "memory");
    exit(1);
}
% strassen/strassen.proto
// /home/cae/OBJ/ovrgen/strassen/strassen.proto -- prototypes

// FILE: /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen/arith.c
// strassen/arith.c -- basic add/sub

    void
    Madd_orig(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int x);

    void
    MaddX(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m);

    void
    Msub_orig(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int x);

    void
    MsubX(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n, int m);

    void
    Madd0(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n);

    void
    Madd1(int *A,int Aoff, int *B,int Boff, int *C, int n);

    void
    Msub0(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n);

    void
    Msub1(int *A,int Aoff, int *B,int Boff, int *C, int n);

// FILE: /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen/core.c
// strassen/core.c -- strassen function

    void
    strassen(int *A, int *B, int *C, int n);

// FILE: /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen/mtx.c
// strassen/mtx.c -- matrix allocation

    int *
    mtxacq(int hgt,int wid,const char *sym);

    void
    mtxrls(int *mtx);

    mtxgeo_t *
    mtxfree(mtxgeo_t *list);

    void
    mtxzero(int *mtx);

    void
    mtxcmp(int *lhsbase,int *rhsbase);

    int *
    _mtxoffchk(int *mtx,int off,int m,int n);

    void
    _geofault(mtxgeo_t *geo,int off,const char *why);

// FILE: /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen/strassen.c
// strassen/strassen.c -- strassen test

    int
    main(void);

// FILE: /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen/tsc.c
// strassen/mtx.c -- matrix allocation

    double
    tscgetf(void);

    void
    _sysfault(void);
% strassen/Makefile
# /home/cae/preserve/ovrbnc/strassen -- makefile
PGMTGT += strassen
CURSRC += arith.c
CURSRC += core.c
CURSRC += mtx.c
CURSRC += tsc.c
ifndef COPTS
    COPTS += -O2
endif
CFLAGS += $(COPTS)
CFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Werror
CFLAGS += -I..
all: $(PGMTGT)
strassen: strassen.c $(CURSRC) $(LIBSRC)
    cc -o strassen $(CFLAGS) strassen.c $(CURSRC) $(LIBSRC)
clean:
    rm -f $(PGMTGT)
```

Comment: Please let me know if/how this is helpful.